# Connecting to database automatically?

Tags: java, database

Hello I have a program that connects to a database online and access's data from a table etc.
Everything works fine when telling my friends to open netbeans first and connect to the database in services. What I need to do it make all that automatic, like running in a jar or something where the code will connect.

What I use for Connection is 'Connection con = ' blah blah
and this connects but I must already be connected to the database in services?

Comment: Back up two steps.  How is this code used?  What portion of it controls the connection?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make your database server run as a service... Try googling about that for your chosen operating system.

Comment: Agree with Jahroy! If you don't want your database server running as a service always. Try running it before running your application jar in a shell/batch script file. I never did that before but I guess this would work if this is what you want.

Comment: The issue was the guys didnt have the drivers, so I had to make sure to open the jars and physically include the library files like derbyclient.jar that the program relied on.

Thanks!

- Its looking like an online chat messenger not, I have a refresh button but would be be ok to auto refresh like every 3 seconds or something. Cant imagine how to know when to update depending on when the person your talking to adds to the online database table?

Answer (score 0):

You can make Connection variable as static. This makes connection to be established on class loading time rather at request processing time.

Comment: This does not address the OPs (broad scoped) issue.

Comment: OP = _Original Poster_ - I thought I was the worst person in the world with acronyms!  In this case I believe the OP is looking for a way to ensure that his database server is automatically running when users attepmt to connect to it.  He says that everything works fine _only_ if he uses NetBeans to start his database server.

Comment: Never mind! I think it's better to convey clearly without using "chat like" words. Anyway, that's me!

Comment: I agree with you in almost all situations... but OP is pretty darn conventional around here.